# .each() function with interval between each iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure if it is possible. The idea is very basic, list of buttons that onload start changing its background with a short interval and then repeat. I have a list of elements like:

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

Next I want to manipulate it one by one, change background and pass to next with short interval. The problem is that it applies changes to all of them at once.

Here is the way I do it:

```
var element = $('.button');         

element.each(function(){
    var thisObj = $(this);

    setInterval(function(){
        thisObj.css({
            'background':'#000'
        })
    }, 1000)
});
```

And then simply repeat it till the mouseover event is detected.

Could anyone suggest a way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: i think you're  better off with setTimeout()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/S7C9h/

Some code to go along with it:

```
var buttons = $('.button'),
    buttons_length = buttons.length;

function sliiide(index, interval){
    var button = buttons.eq(index%buttons_length);
    if(button.css('background-color') == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)'){ //blue
        button.css({
            background: 'white'
        });
    }
    else {
        button.css({
            background: 'blue'
        });
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        sliiide(++index, interval);
    }, interval)
}


sliiide(0, 500);
```

This uses `setTimeout` **instead** of `setInterval` to reduce bubbling of the timeout events.

---

Update based on your comments below: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/gMDEM/4/

Comment: Hi, your version is just what I am trying to implement. Although I have a question. Why my last line is not removing the class? Please take a look http://jsfiddle.net/gMDEM/

Comment: @Alex thats bc the 1st element doesnt have a `.prev()` let me update it. one minute.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood what you want to do. Would this work?

```
var element = $('.button');         

    element.each(function(index){
        var thisObj = $(this);

        setTimeout(function(){
          setInterval(function(){
              thisObj.css({
                  'background':'#000'
              })
          },1000);
        },1000 * index);

    });
```

So each interval will begin with 1 second of difference.

Did I understood right?

Comment: I think the outer call should be a setTimeout or things would get pretty crazy! But I'm not sure if the OP actually wants a setInterval at all...

Answer (score 0):

If  you only want the effect to happen once you should use `setTimeout` not `setInterval`. `setInterval` sets up a repeating event. Maybe you should try something like...

```
var element = $('.button');         
    var offsetTime = 1000;
    element.each(function(){
        var thisObj = $(this);


        setInterval(function(){
            thisObj.css({
                'background':'#000'
            })
        },offsetTime)
        offsetTime += 1000;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you should use different intervals for each button. In addition it is better to use setTimeout instead of setInterval, as the latter can cause performance issues:

```
   var $element = $('.button');         

    $element.each(function(index, button){
        var $button = $(button);

        setTimeout(function changeColor(){
                    $button.css({'background':'#000'});
                    setTimeout(changeColor, 1000);
        }, 1000*index);
    });
```